# strong inquality?

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

**Suppose $a,b,c$ are positive real number. Prove that
$$\dfrac{a(b+c)}{(a+b)(a+c)}+\dfrac{b(c+a)}{(b+a)(b+c)}+\dfrac{c(a+b)}{(c+a)(c+b)}\ge \dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}.$$**

I 'd tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz's :
$$LHS=\sum_{\{a,b,c\}}\dfrac{(a(b+c))^2}{a(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)}\ge \dfrac{4(ab+bc+ca)^2}{(a+b+c)(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}.$$
After that, I used $p,q,r$ tranformation and need to prove
$$\dfrac{4q^2}{p(pq-r)}\ge \dfrac{p^2}{2(p^2-2q)}$$
I wonder if it is a true inequality?
Somebody help me? Or give me some hint?

Comment: @Vasya I dont think thats a counter example

Comment: sorry sir. I have some mistake in typing :(

Comment: Expanding out all of the terms work.

Comment: Your inequality isn't true because when you cross multiply, the major term on the RHS is $a^5b$, while the major term on the LHS is only $a^4 b^2 $. So, to find a counterexample, take $ b = c = 1$, which gives $ 8(2a+1)^2(a^2 + 2 ) \geq 2(a+2)^3(a+1)^2$, and it's clear that the RHS wins out for large enough $a$ (like $a=7$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We write the inequality as
$$2+\frac{8abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} \geqslant \frac{(a+b+c)^{2}}{a^2+b^2+c^2}.$$
But
$$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) \leqslant \frac{8}{9}(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2).$$
It's remain to prove that
$$2+\frac{9abc}{(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)} \geqslant \frac{(a+b+c)^{2}}{a^2+b^2+c^2},$$
equivalent to
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+\frac{9abc}{a+b+c} \geqslant 2(ab+bc+ca).$$
Which is true. The proof is completed.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the modified inequality isn't always true.

Here's an approach to solve the original inequality:

We use the symmetric-sum notation $ (x, y, z) = \sum_{sym} a^xb^yc^z$ to simplify the algebraic manipulations.

Cross multiplying the denominator, we have

Original inequality
$\Leftrightarrow [ (2,1,0) + (1,1,1) ] \times 2 ( 2,0,0) \geq [( 2,0,0) + 2 (1,1,0)]  \times [ (2,1,0) + 1/3 (1,1,1) ] $
$ \Leftrightarrow 2(4, 1, 0 ) + 2(3, 2, 0 ) + 6( 3, 1, 1) + 2 (2,2,1)\geq  
(4,1,0) + 3 (3,2,0) + 3 (3, 1, 1) + 3 (3, 2, 0) + 5 (2, 2, 1) $
$\Leftrightarrow (4,1,0) + 3 (3, 1, 1)    \geq (3, 2, 0) + 3 (2, 2, 1) $.

The last inequality is true by Muirhead term wise.